# How to stitch images by openCV with masks? (Only stitch parts of images)

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I was trying to stitch images with OpenCV stitcher.

Some of the feed in images have some black areas left by previous processing and they cause some trouble while stitching.

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWaGe.jpg)

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfCU0.png)

[Third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDmqf.jpg)

[Forth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD0SE.jpg)

And my code is like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Stitch several images.')

parser.add_argument("-i","--inputfiles", type = str, help = "the input files", nargs='+')
parser.add_argument("-o","--outputfiles", type = str, help = "the output files")

args = parser.parse_args()

print "input: " + str(args.inputfiles)
print "potential output: " + args.outputfiles

stitcher = cv2.createStitcherScans(True)
arrayOfImage = []    
for imageName in args.inputfiles:
    arrayOfImage.append(cv2.imread(imageName))
stitchingResult = stitcher.stitch(arrayOfImage)    
cv2.imwrite(args.outputfiles,stitchingResult[1])
```

And I use command

```
python stitchingImages.py -i 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png -o result.png
```

to test it.

The result is 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SrOW.png)

I think the problem is the black areas are recognised as strong features. Is there any way to exclude them from the feature detection and blending?