# How to use stitch() passing a mask

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching

Even if there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415910/how-to-stitch-images-by-opencv-with-masks-only-stitch-parts-of-images) (unanswered). I will give more details to try to solve it, also this question will be based on C++.

So, imagine we have 3 images and we want to stitch them, but we know that they don't fully overlap, so, to improve the results we should be able to pass a mask on each pair of images to tell the future detector where to look for key points. The [documentation is a bit confusing](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html):

```
Status cv::Stitcher::stitch (   InputArrayOfArrays  images,
InputArrayOfArrays  masks,
OutputArray     pano 
)
```

> These functions try to stitch the given images.

> Parameters
>
> images:    Input images.
>
> masks:     Masks for each input image specifying where to look for keypoints (optional).
>
> pano:  Final pano.
>
> Returns
> Status code.

I guess that `masks` should be a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s of `cv::Mat`s of size NxN where N is the amount of images. And each `cv::Mat` tells the function where to mask the image when matching 2 images. i.e. the `cv::Mat` in (0,1) will mask image 1 when finding points to match on image 0 and the one in (1,2) will mask the image when finding key points to match between image 1 and 2.

I tried this by declaring masks full of ones:

```
    cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("my_path_1", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread("my_path_2", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    cv::Mat image3 = cv::imread("my_path_3", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    // The 3 of them have the same size !!

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
    images.push_back(image1);
    images.push_back(image2);
    images.push_back(image3);

    cv::Mat result;

    // Deinfe here the masks !!
    cv::Mat onesTemplate = cv::Mat::ones(image1.size(), CV_8UC1);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>> matArray(3, std::vector<cv::Mat>(3, onesTemplate));

    auto mode = cv::Stitcher::PANORAMA;

    auto stitcher = cv::Stitcher::create(mode);

    // Set params here if needed
    cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(images, matArray, result);

    if (status == cv::Stitcher::OK) {
        std::string fileName = "something"
        cv::imwrite(fileName, result);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Stitching failed: ";
        if (status == cv::Stitcher::ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS) {
            std::cerr << "Insufficient images to perform stitching." << std::endl;
        } else if (status == cv::Stitcher::ERR_HOMOGRAPHY_EST_FAIL) {
            std::cerr << "Homography estimation failed." << std::endl;
        } else if (status == cv::Stitcher::ERR_CAMERA_PARAMS_ADJUST_FAIL) {
            std::cerr << "Camera parameter adjustment failed." << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Unknown error." << std::endl;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

When I compile/run this I get the following error:

```
In file included from /cache/venv/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:55,
                 from /cache/venv/include/opencv4/opencv2/features2d.hpp:47,
                 from /source/stiching_app/src/main.cpp:9:
/cache/venv/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/traits.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct cv::traits::Type<cv::Mat>’:
/cache/venv/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:126:60:   required from ‘cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(const std::vector<std::vector<_Tp> >&) [with _Tp = cv::Mat]’
/source/stiching_app/src/main.cpp:130:51:   required from here
/cache/venv/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/traits.hpp:386:31: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘cv::DataType<cv::Mat>’
  386 | { enum { value = DataType<T>::type }; };
      |                               ^~~~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stitching.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/stitching.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/stitching.dir/all] Error 2
```

Which makes me think I'm just using the wrong object type as `cv::DataType< _Tp >` only accepts:

> A primitive OpenCV data type is one of unsigned char, bool, signed char, unsigned short, signed short, int, float, double, or a tuple of values of one of these types, where all the values in the tuple have the same type.

and not a `cv::Mat`

The question is, what should I send instead?

Note that I achieve stitching images with my code if I call  `stitch()` with only 2 parameters:

```
cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(images, result); // this is ok
```

Comment: "ArrayOfArrays" -> `vector` of `Mat`s. Just like you have with `images`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md#feature-masking) brings you on the correct path